# Umbraco: Create custom tree without separate project/DLL?

Tags: umbraco

I need to add a **custom tree** to a custom section of a "Web Site" (ie. a folder in the inetpub directory of a server)

I could do it by creating a new project (hence a new DLL), and copying the DLL to the bin folder of the website. But that will create a dependency to another project outside the website, which is not acceptable in my case.

Is there a way to create a custom tree without creating a separate DLL (eg. by just creating a Class in the AppCode folder)?

Is there a way to put in a Class name (instead of DLL name) in the *treeHandlerAssembly* column in the *umbracoAppTree* table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
This article helped me http://www.shazwazza.com/post/Dynamically-registering-custom-trees-without-writing-to-UmbracoAppTree.aspx

Other than that I couldn't find any help anywhere else, hope this will help someone.

```
  static object _locker = new object();

  /// <summary>
  /// Adds a custom tree to a custom section in Umbraco
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="customTreeType">Your custom tree that is inherited from BaseTree</param>
  /// <param name="alias">Your custom section alias</param>
  public static void RenderCustomTree(Type customTreeType, string alias)
  {
      // Check if customTree is already registered
      if (TreeDefinitionCollection.Instance.Count(x => x.TreeType == customTreeType) == 0)
      {
        lock (_locker)
        {
          // Double check
          if (TreeDefinitionCollection.Instance.Count(x => x.TreeType == customTreeType) == 0)
          {
            Application customApp = new Application(alias, alias, ".traycontent");

            // Create the tree definition
            var myCustomTree = new TreeDefinition(customTreeType,
                                  new umbraco.BusinessLogic.ApplicationTree(true, true, 0,
                                      alias,                      //applicationAlias,
                                      alias,                      //alias
                                      alias,                      //title
                                      ".sprTreeFolder",           //iconClosed
                                      ".sprTreeFolder_o",         //iconOpened
                                      "uComponents.Core",         //assemblyName
                                      customTreeType.ToString(),  //type
                                      null),                      //action
                                  customApp);

            // Add our tree definition to the collection at runtime
            TreeDefinitionCollection.Instance.Add(myCustomTree);
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

And in your own class inherited from IHttpModule:

```
  public void Init(HttpApplication application)
  {
    RenderCustomTree(typeof(YourCustomTree), "yourCustomSection");
  }
```